# Identify this music track used in 50s and 60s sci-fi films dubbed into Spanish

Tags: music, music-identification

I have a question that maybe someone may be able to help me with.

I grew up in South America and all Scifi films from the 50's and 60's were dubbed into Spanish. Very often the company doing the dubbing reused the same music track for different films from the 60s. I remember hearing the same track in all movies with Robby the robot, for example.

It was a nice orchestral music and I would like to find it.

Based on my memories I made a wav file with a fragment of the melody. the wav file is located here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7d465d521z4kux0/scifi.wav?dl=0

Does anyone recognize this music ?

Comment: This is a really interesting question, I hope someone can help you out here.

Comment: Can you date the dubbing or when you saw them?